# TypeError: this.io is undefined socket.io.js:639

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I try to connect from JavaScript to nodejs socket-server (for using webrtc in phonegap - PhoneRTC plugin)

I have server.js code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var webRTC = require('webrtc.io').listen(server);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 1234;
server.listen(port);




app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.get('/style.css', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/style.css');
});

app.get('/fullscrean.png', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/fullscrean.png');
});

app.get('/script.js', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/script.js');
});

app.get('/webrtc.io.js', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/webrtc.io.js');
});





webRTC.rtc.on('chat_msg', function(data, socket) {
  var roomList = webRTC.rtc.rooms[data.room] || [];

  for (var i = 0; i < roomList.length; i++) {
    var socketId = roomList[i];

    if (socketId !== socket.id) {
      var soc = webRTC.rtc.getSocket(socketId);

      if (soc) {
        soc.send(JSON.stringify({
          "eventName": "receive_chat_msg",
          "data": {
            "messages": data.messages,
            "color": data.color
          }
        }), function(error) {
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
});
```

start it: node server.js

then i have client side code:

```
<script src="http://my-saite:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>



<script>
    // Create SocketIO instance, connect

    var socket = new io.Socket();

    socket.connect('http://my-saite:1234'); 

    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('connect',function() {
      alert ('Client has connected to the server!');
    });
    // Add a connect listener
    socket.on('message',function(data) {
      alert ('Received a message from the server!',data);
    });
    // Add a disconnect listener
    socket.on('disconnect',function() {
      alert ('The client has disconnected!');
    });

    // Sends a message to the server via sockets
    function sendMessageToServer(message) {
      socket.send(message);
    };
</script>
```

and when i open it in web-browser i get error: TypeError: this.io is undefined socket.io.js:639

http://my-saite.com:1234 and http://my-saite.com:1234/socket.io/socket.io.js load fine,
 639 line in socket.io.js is

```
/**
 * `Socket` constructor.
 *
 * @api public
 */

function Socket(io, nsp){
  this.io = io;
  this.nsp = nsp;
  this.json = this; // compat
  this.ids = 0;
  this.acks = {};
/*639 line --->*/  if (this.io.autoConnect) this.open();
  this.receiveBuffer = [];
  this.sendBuffer = [];
  this.connected = false;
  this.disconnected = true;
  this.subEvents();
}
```

If someone has faced a similar problem - help. I would be grateful for your advice!

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: hi. the laster version - 1.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Using version 1.1.0 I guess?

Change the creation of a Socket object

```
var socket = io.connect('http://my-saite:1234');
```

Then the rest shouldn't be a problem

```
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect',function() {
  alert ('Client has connected to the server!');
});
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('message',function(data) {
  alert ('Received a message from the server!',data);
});
// Add a disconnect listener
socket.on('disconnect',function() {
  alert ('The client has disconnected!');
});

// Sends a message to the server via sockets
function sendMessageToServer(message) {
  socket.send(message);
};
```